# How can I print a 128-255 character from an integer in C?

Tags: c, char, ascii

I'm still playing around with C to understand how it works.

I'm having trouble printing characters from the extended ASCII table (128-255). If I do `printf("Â")` (for example), it prints Â (everything works fine). However, if I assign a variable, for instance `a = 194`, and then print the variable `printf("%c",a)`, it prints � instead of Â.

By the way it works fine with the 32-127 characters (for example, 35 prints *#*).

How could I print one of the 128-255 characters from an integer (decimal or binary)?

I am using GCC 11.3 on [Ubuntu 20.04.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) LTS.

Comment: There is no standard "extended ASCII table". Your terminal probably uses UTF-8 encoding, which uses multiple bytes for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Printing in what context? In a terminal window? Which terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely both your compiler and the terminal use UTF-8 to encode non-ASCII characters.

Character sets and encodings is a vast subject, with many different and incompatible conventions and implementations.  `Â` indeed is encoded as 194 on legacy single byte encodings such as `ISO8859-1` and `Windows-1252`. It is also the character number in the Unicode standard, that has more than 100000 different code points to represent almost every language and symbol set in the world.

There are different ways to represent these characters as sequences of bytes, the most ubiquitous of which is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), used in 99% of web pages. ASCII characters in the range 32-127 are represented as single bytes, and those with a greater code-point use between 2 and 4 bytes, a leading byte in the range `C2` to `F4` and 1 to 3 trailing bytes in the range `80` to `BF`.  `Â` is encoded as `C3 82`, which means `"Â"` is actually a 2 byte string identical to `"\xC3\x82"`.

You can verify this with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "Â";
    int len = strlen(s);
    printf("%s: len=%d, bytes=", s, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%02hhX%c", s[i], " \n"[i == len - 1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be `Â: len=2, bytes=C3 82`.

To convert non-ASCII characters to UTF-8 sequences on output streams, you can use the locale functions from `<locale.h>` and wide character output:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    printf("%lc\n", 194);
```

Output:

```
Â
```

If the locale is correctly configured in the terminal, you can select the default locale with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @interjay, as well as written on Wikipedia:

> ... There is no formal definition of "extended ASCII", and even the use of the term is sometimes criticized because it can be mistakenly interpreted to mean that the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) had updated its ANSI X3.4-1986 standard to include more characters, or that the term identifies a single unambiguous encoding, neither of which is the case. ...

*[Wikipedia: Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)*

---

Also, you are able to print Â while using `printf("Â");` because you are using it as a string. Â is interpreted as a Unicode character (by both your compiler and your terminal). You can check it via compiling the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c = 'Â'; // set single character variable to be Â

    printf("%c", c); // print the variable

    return 0;
}
```

On my system, my compiler gives me this warning:

```
extended_ascii.c: In function ‘main’:
extended_ascii.c:4:18: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    4 |         char c = 'Â'; // set single character variable to be Â
      |                  ^~~
extended_ascii.c:4:18: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘50050’ to ‘-126’ [-Woverflow]
```

which suggests that Â is indeed a Unicode multi-byte character.

---

You can also try running this code to check what Â expands to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c[] = "Â"; // set a string variable to be Â

    for(int i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++) { // loop through each character
        printf("%d ", c[i]); // print integer value of each character
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and, its output:

```
-61 -126
```

So, your Â is a multi-byte character expanding to those values. If you try printing each of these characters separately, you will again see ��. Thus, when printed together, the terminal would interpret it as a Unicode character and print the desired result.

---

BTW, I also found this on the internet:

> In the Windows-1252 character set, ASCII code 194 is represented by the character Â ...

Notice the use of the words *Windows-1252 character set*. Although I have no idea about that character set, the most probable reason for `194` not printing as `Â` might be due to your terminal not supporting that character set.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble printing characters from the extended ASCII table (128-255).

Sorry, but there's no such a thing (extended ASCII table) and ASCII exends only from 0 to 127 (giving a total of 128 characters)  The question you ask actually depends on the character set and the C support for that is in the internationalization library.

You have first to decide on as character set that is supported by the output device (this is the terminal ---virtual or real--- at which you are printing the characters) then, encode everything in that character set, and you will see the expected output.